# Log into FogBugz through c# application

Tags: c#, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I am trying to login into fogbugz using my c# application.I am using FogBugz XML API.
The code that I am currently using is:

```
   <form method="post" action="https://xxxxx.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=logon">
   Email:
   <input type="text" value="email" name="email">
   <br />    
   Password:
   <input type="password" value="password" name="password">
   <br /> 
   <input type="submit">
   <br />
   </form>
```

When I do this I do get logged into FogBugz.I get an XML file as output where I have my token under  tags.

Is there any way to make the user see an aspx file and not the XML file but I could use the XML file and cache the token value?
I am new to FogBugz please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [FogLampz](http://foglampz.codeplex.com/).

It allows you to write code such as:

```
FogBugzClient.LogOn("https://myproject.fogbugz.com/api.asp", 
"email@mydomain.com", "password");

var projects = FogBugzClient.GetProjects();
var areas = FogBugzClient.GetAreas();
```

Use this in your code-behind for your aspx page. (you wont need your form action pointing to fogbugz)

You can then display/modify/do-anything-to the results as you wish.

Alternatively there is the [Fogbugz Csharp API Wrapper](http://asp.net2.aspfaq.com/fogbugz-csharp-api-wrapper.html) which allows very similar coding style to pull out FogBugz data.

Comment: :thank you for your suggestion.I checked out Foglampz.When I downloaded it ,I got the DLL version of it.I cannot refer it in my code. I tired to do Using FogLampz but nothing is working.! Please help!Thankyou